# (Bootstrap validation)validator.js is not working in mvc4

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrapvalidator

Here is my bootstrap form which I want to validate using bootstrap validation.
its works well in static html page .

```
<form id="myform" data-toggle="validator" role="form">    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I included all the required file (js+css). you can see js file in the image css are not visible in image .

[image]

Everything looks well but is not validating email .

Can someone help me what I did wrong ?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code and your approach, http://jsfiddle.net/2tz41snj/ you may need to check `validator.js` may be it's corrupt

Comment: Do the files actually exist in the /Scripts/ directory?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem ?